# Playframework unusual CPU load

Tags: scala, nginx, playframework, playframework-2.0, docker

Recently we started using PlayFramework and seeing some unusual activity in CPU load.

Machine details and other configurations:

```
32G Machine
12  Cores
PlayFramework 2.2.0
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
java applications are running within a docker container(Docker version 0.8.0).
```

There are 6 play server running behind nginx

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
31752 root      20   0 7876m 1.2g  14m S  716  3.8 150:55.28 java
26282 root      20   0 7862m 1.2g  14m S   48  3.8 310:51.65 java
56449 root      20   0 7789m 389m  13m S    2  1.2   0:33.10 java
40006 root      20   0 7863m 1.2g  14m S    2  3.8  17:56.41 java
42896 root      20   0 7830m 1.2g  14m S    1  3.8  15:10.30 java
52119 root      20   0 7792m 1.2g  14m S    1  3.7   8:48.38 java
```

The request rate is at max 100Req/s.

Has anyone faced this similar issues before?
Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, unrelated, but are your running those webapps as `root`? I hope that's a VM, and even then...

Comment: Any details about deployment(s)?

Comment: Yes those apps are running within a docker container.

Comment: Its basically storing some data in DB and reading from database

Comment: I also started the app outside the container to isolate issues with docker and the pattern still continues. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing a similar issue. However, I am only having trouble with the dev setup on my machine:

- play! application started via *play run*
- within a docker container
- that is running inside a VM

-> 100% CPU load inside the VM

Problem does *not* exist in our live environment, where the application is run pre-packaged via the *start* script. We also have it running in a docker container there (which in turn runs in an EC2 VM).

So it seems like in my case *play run* makes a difference - are you using *play run* to start your app inside the docker container?

EDIT: Also, there seems to be a bug in Netty related to *epoll selectors*:
http://www.electrotank.com/forums/showthread.php?12927-Well-Known-JDK-bug-in-Netty
https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/issues/detail?id=279

The second link describes a workaround that involves setting the *-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction* JVM parameter to 80 or something.

In my case, this did not help however...

You might consider profiling your java process e.g. using

```
sudo strace -cf -p <pid>
```

and see if anything suspicious shows up.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the play app? I have experienced a similar high load when running with `play ~run`, because it watches files for changes constantly.